# A react app inside a monorepo (lerna) package causing conflicting 'react' package

Tags: reactjs, npm, monorepo, lerna, npm-package

I created :

- A reusable react component package, and
- A react app for testing the component

Both of them are inside a monorepo (lerna).
The problem is the "react" packages for the component & for the app are pointed to "different thing", thus using hook inside the component triggers this error:
"Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component".

Deleting the second "react" package directory will affect to the component project because it's a symbolic linking (similar to shortcut to component project).
Any idea for resolving my problem?[image]

Comment: If you're using webpack you can create an `alias` for `react` and `react-dom` inside `my-react-app` that points to `<path-to-my-react-app/node_modules/react` and similarly for `react-dom`.

Comment: i'm using a react-script and and won't to eject it.

Comment: Then try what it says at the bottom of this doc: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html. Link the react from your lib, to the react in your app.

Answer (score 0):

1. clean all the node_modules.
2. use peer dependencies in react component.

l use that two steps slove react version conflict problem in monorepo.
You can try it.